# Data Rearrangement using python Pandas | Create a column based on repeated index and fill with the column value

Tags: python, database, pandas, csv

Rearranging python csv data into rows and different column
I have csv dtabase which contains the name and friend list in below format

[image]

Expected output like as below:
Name and Value in one row with the number of repeated columns as per the name repetition.

[image]

What is the best way to perform this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use groupby and create a new Dataframe with `from_dict` :

```
new_dict = (df.groupby('Name')
              .apply(lambda x: list(map(lambda x: x, x['Value'])))
              .to_dict())

new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_dict, orient='index')
```

This will give you :

```
           0      1      2
Ajay    C529   C530   None
Djna   A-506  A-507  A-508
Patc2  B-526  B-527  B-528
```

Comment: Thanks @LilianBordeau . It works, the Column name is appearing 0,1,2/...How to change it to Value-1,value-2,value3..... etc.

Comment: As @anky_91 suggested, just add new_df.columns=['value_'+str(i+1) for i in new_df.columns]

Comment: @LilianBordeau Good one. +1

Comment: I have added   new_df.add_suffix('_Value'), It works . Thansk @anky_91

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you would need `df.pivot()` and then shift the values to the left:

```
df_new=df.pivot(index='Name',columns='Value',values='Value')\
.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), axis=1).fillna(np.nan)
df_new.columns=['value_'+str(i+1) for i in df_new.columns]
print(df_new)

    value_1 value_2 value_3 value_4 value_5 value_6 value_7 value_8 value_9  \
Name                                                                            
Ajay     C529    C530    C531    C532    C533    C534    C535     NaN     NaN   
Djna    A-506   A-507   A-508   A-509   A-510   A-511   A-512   A-513   A-514   
Patc2   B-526   B-527   B-528     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   

      value_10  
Name            
Ajay       NaN  
Djna     A-515  
Patc2      NaN
```

Comment: This is run with an error df_new=df.pivot(index='Name',columns='Value',values='Value').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), axis=1).fillna(np.nan)
df_new.columns=['value_'+str(i+1) for i in df_new.columns]
print(df_new)      " Index contains duplicate entries, '
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"